# Ошибка "Abnormal build process termination" в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Пару дней назад решил начать осваивать Java (До этого работал на Си). В консоли все работает отлично, решил перейти на IDEA. Столкнулся с данной проблемой. В CLion при компиляции С/Срр подобная проблема тоже есть, но она решается простым подключением соответствующей библиотеки. Тут не помогло. В чем проблема? Заранее благодарю.

Компиляция через консоль проходит успешно, все работает. IDEA компилировать отказывается.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Текст ошибки от IDEA:

> Error:Abnormal build process termination:  "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=654740390749071760 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -Djps.file.types.component.name=FileTypeManager -Duser.language=ru -Duser.country=RU -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2017.1 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users-vboiko-.IntelliJIdea2017.1\config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users-vboiko-.IntelliJIdea2017.1\config\plugins
>   -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/log/build-log
>   "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ
>   IDEA 2017.1/jre64" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=1.8.0_112-release
>   -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/compile-server/untitled_17d5ef6c/*temp*
>   -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.experimental=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users-vboiko-\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-2481521604479275026-is-running\"
>   -classpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar"
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/lib/xercesImpl.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/batik-all.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/lib/netty-all-4.1.6.Final.Patched.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/openapi.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ
>   IDEA 2017.1/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/oromatcher.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/asm-all.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/lib/snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/jna.jar;;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-cli-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-logging-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-core-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-groovy-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-process-services-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-resources-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-version-info-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-3.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/jansi-1.14.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/kryo-2.22.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/minlog-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-0.12.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-libcpp-0.12.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-libstdcpp-0.12.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-libcpp-0.12.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-libstdcpp-0.12.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.12.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-ncurses5-0.12.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-ncurses6-0.12.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-0.12.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-ncurses5-0.12.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-ncurses6-0.12.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-amd64-0.12.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-i386-0.12.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-amd64-0.12.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-i386-0.12.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/reflectasm-1.07.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1/lib/gson-2.5.jar;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/maven/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/maven/lib/aether-1.1.0-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/maven/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/osmorc-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/bndlib-3.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/bnd-repository-3.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/bnd-resolve-3.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/osmorc/lib/bundlor-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/aspectj/lib/aspectj-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/flex/lib/flex-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/flex/lib/flex-shared.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/jpa-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/webSphereIntegration/lib/jps/webSphere-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/jps/weblogic-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/dmServer/lib/dmServer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/GwtStudio/lib/gwt-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/google-app-engine-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/appEngine-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-compiler-patch.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-gradle-jps.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/repository.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/sdklib.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-library.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/compiler-settings.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/nailgun.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/scala-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/sbt-interface.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/incremental-compiler.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/jline.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/dotty-interfaces.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-library.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-play-2-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Users/-vboiko-/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/config/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin.jar;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
>   2017.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 56121
>   27b58e07-277c-4a3f-874e-fc890c2bf50a

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь сам текст ошибки. Обрати внимание, что hello все таки вывелось, и возможно ошибка не связана с кодом

Comment: Была такая же проблема, просто перезагрузила компьютер и все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй переустановить JDK, и заново задать его путь

Answer (score 1):

По какой-то причине происходит падение JVM. Попробуйте добавить флаг компиляции `-XX:ErrorFile=/tmp/hs_err_pid_%p.log` и проверить логи для определения конкретной причины.

---

Судя по [комментариям](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681482/intellij-errorabnormal-build-process-termination) других пользователей проблема, скорее всего, связана с драйверами Nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема была из-за драйвера Nvidia 385.69.
Обновление драйвера решило проблему. Каким бы странным это не казалось.